# Setting value of an attribute when uploading file to database

Tags: java, sqlite, csv

I have a .csv file "Salesman" that will be uploaded to the sqlite database. This file contains details about a Salesman.

A sample row for Salesman:

```
-----------
|code|name|
-----------
|0001|Jon|
-----------
|0002|Stu|
```

DDL for Salesman:

```
CREATE TABLE salesman (
code       INTEGER NOT NULL,
name       TEXT    NOT NULL,
isSelected INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (
    code
)
);
```

The attribute `isSelected` acts as a tag stating that the Salesman has been selected, thus cannot be chosen again.

This is my code for getting Salesman details from .CSV file:

```
public static ArrayList<Salesman> getSalesmanFromFile(String filePath){
    ArrayList<Salesman> salesmanList= new ArrayList<Salesman>();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line = null;
        String[] strSalesman = null;            
        try {
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null){
                strSalesman = line.split(",");
                salesmanList.add(new Salesman(Integer.parseInt(strSalesman[0]), strSalesman[1]));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        String status = "Error"; //- Please review file selected. Make sure that format is followed.";
    }
    return salesmanList;
}
```

My question is, how can I set the third attribute `isSelected` in the method to 0 (not selected)? Since .csv file doesn't contain the tagging attribute, I'm thinking of placing it in the method above (which will be used at the start of the whole program).

I'm thinking of creating a variable within the method `int isSelected = 0` but I don't know how to incorporate it with the `BufferedReader`. Something like:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String line = null;
    String[] strSalesman = null;            
    //int isSelected = 0;
    try {
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null){
            strSalesman = line.split(",");
            salesmanList.add(new Salesman(Integer.parseInt(strSalesman[0]), strSalesman[1], isSelected?));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: whats wrong with what you are currently doing ? if you always want the isSelected be dafaulted to false, then yes just pass 0 with your constructor.

Comment: homaygosh that's true... man, it's the basics that get me. thank you so much @dumb_terminal!